# How to combine multiple onclick events/elements

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick, toggle

I have this toggle function which has multiple buttons.

```
var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
var button3 = document.querySelector('#button3');

var toggleState = function (elem, one, two) {
var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === one ? two : one); //ternary operator
};

button1.onclick = function (e) {
toggleState('#div1', 'open', 'closed');
e.preventDefault();
};

button2.onclick = function (e) {
toggleState('#div2', 'open', 'closed');
e.preventDefault();
};

button3.onclick = function (e) {
toggleState('#div3', 'open', 'closed');
e.preventDefault();
};
```

I've tried querySelectorAll to combine variables but it doesn't work.  I think I know why. But I can't figure out a way to write the script more eloquently.  (scratch eloquently. respectable is a better word)

How can I combine variables and onclicks so that the code is not so redundant?

Comment: You could use an anonymous array and iterate over it like `['#button1', '#button2'].foreach(item, index){ //handle items with same logic }`

Comment: Find the closest ancestor element of buttons (or wrap them into such element), and attach only a single listener to that ancestor. Then in the handler function you can make a difference between the buttons by their id (or use data-* attribute), and extract the number part of the id to get a reference to the divs to toggle. Also `event.target` will contain a reference to the clicked button.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to write out the code?  I suppose I can look up anonymous array and try to hack together the working code but that could take hours for me.

Comment: @Teemu, there is no closes ancestor element of buttons.  Are you saying I need to wrap buttons with a parent element?  And attaching a single listener is fine but that's the part I am struggling with.  I understand what you are saying conceptually but I actually need to learn how to write out the code.

Comment: @HackYa There's always a common ancestor, `body` if nothing else. Though it's recommended to find some closer element, or add a wrapper if possible. You've already accepted a fine answer here, so I'm not going to give an answer. You can search for "event delegation" at SO to find answers, which explain in details the concept, and also contain some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a solution similar to the one below. Instead of copying the event handler per element, you could process each of the elements in a loop.

If the element ids are consistent, you could make it even briefer by only specifying the number of toggles and generating the ids on the fly.

```
var toggles = {
    '#button1': '#div1',
    '#button2': '#div2',
    '#button3': '#div3'
};

Object.keys(toggles).forEach(function(toggle) {
    document.querySelector(toggle).onclick = function (e) {
        toggleState(toggles[toggle], 'open', 'closed');
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});

function toggleState(elem, one, two) {
    var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
    elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === one ? two : one);
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me basis to build my understanding from.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

You need to get `button` elements and trigger an `onclick` event for them.

Instead of trigger `onclick` event handler per each button, you could use a loop.

Read more about [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var toggleState = function (elem, one, two) {
    var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
    elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === one ? two : one); //ternary operator
};
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
     var button=document.querySelector('#button'+(i+1));
     button.onclick=(function(index){;
        toggleState('#div'+index,'open','closed');
     }).bind(this,i+1);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I do like Timo's example better only because I have more to learn from his.